# bash script can't seem to execute linux commands

Tags: linux, bash

I am writing a bash script that is suppose to auto restart my autofs in a loop. but when I try to run it I just get a syntax error.

```
#./dd_nfs.sh
./dd_nfs.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `/etc/init.d/autofs'
./dd_nfs.sh: line 3: `/etc/init.d/autofs reload'

# cat dd_nfs.sh
    #!/bin/bash
    for i in `seq 1 10`
    /etc/init.d/autofs reload
    sleep 5
    echo "read test"
    do time echo "read"
    echo "read test done"
    done
```

I tried the dos2unix. I replaced line 3 with just 'pwd' to print my current dir and I tried to strip out the /r but I still get the same error. So I am not sure what's going here.

Has anyone seen this before?
Thanks

Comment: The pattern for bash is `for ... do ... done`. You missed the `do`

Comment: you need a line `do` after the for loop definition, before the `autofs reload` line

Comment: do is there, I just commented it out along with the bulk of the code.

Comment: The `do` has to be immediately after the `for`; you can't just add it on some arbitrary line. The line you added in the edit will just cause another syntax error. Consult the bash documentation for the syntax of a `for` loop.

Comment: Your edit also changed the indentation of the script after the `cat` command. That matters; the `#!` must be at the very beginning of the line. Please include an actual copy-and-pasted script in your question, one that reproduces the problem. If your original script is too big, reduce it to something smaller, verify that the problem occurs with the smaller script, and copy-and-paste that into your question. By editing your script without checking it, you've been introducing new errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the wrong syntax for the `for` loop. It requires the `do` keyword.

Change this:

```
for i in `seq 1 10`
```

to this:

```
for i in `seq 1 10` ; do
```

Or, if you prefer, you can write it like this:

```
for in in `seq 1 10`
do
    # body of loop
done
```

(Also, indenting your code would make it easier to read.)

Since you're using bash, the `$(command)` syntax is IMHO easier to read than `` `command` ``:

```
for i in $(seq 1 10) ; do
```

And bash provides a special syntax for simple ranges:

```
for i in {1..10} ; do
```

---

In response to your latest edit, you added this line:

```
do time echo "read"
```

in the body of the loop. The `do` keyword is a syntax error in that context. The shell might not report it because of the previous syntax error caused by the missing `do` at the top of the loop.

Comment: ah sorry, the do part is commented out by me. i will update my post to reflect that.

Comment: I got it working now. I misunderstood where the do should be. I thought it should go in front of the contents of the for loop but it doesn't. Thanks

Comment: @D.Zou: It does go in front of the body of the `for` loop. You added it to the middle of the `for` loop.